# Find out Organization server address in Azure DevOps Server (Installed locally)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I've installed Azure Devops Server 2019 on my local server. Now I want to setup a agent pool. To do this, the I've to follow instructions in the image below.

[image]

As here, I just downloaded the zip file an ran the `config.cmd` file, in the first step, it requires **Server Url** which as I searched over the net, people enter the Organization Url there.

The problem is I have no organization in my local Azure Devops! and when I click on the logo, It redirects me to project collection page:

[image]

What should I enter as Server Url in configuring Agent pool?

Comment: Hi @Hamed Zakery Miab, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Comment: Hi @VitoLiu-MSFT, My original problem was something else, but I found the URL, thanks to remind, I'll answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with bryanbcook,

We can check the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops-2019#server-url-and-authentication) and switch the doc version to Azure DevOps Server 2019 to check the Server Url, it should be `https://{your_server}/tfs`

You can refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops-2019) to configure the self-hosted agent.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Azure DevOps Services, which are hosted in the cloud, and Azure DevOps Sever 20XX use slightly different terminology. The term “Organization” and “Project Collection” refer to the same thing.